# Appending Jquery Var to a function URL

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

Here I would like to append the variable arr_icao and dep_icao to the url

```
var arr_icao = document.getElementById("arr_icao").value;
var dep_icao = document.getElementById("dep_icao").value;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost/position/route_finder/" + arr_icao + dep_icao,
    success: function (data) {
        $(".route-results").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is preventing you from achieving that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like

```
var newUrl = "http://localhost/position/route_finder/" + arr_icao +"" + dep_icao;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: newUrl,
    success: function(data) {
        $(".route-results").html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change from

```
url: "http://localhost/position/route_finder/" + arr_icao + dep_icao,
```

to

```
url: "http://localhost/position/route_finder/" + arr_icao + "/" + dep_icao,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep adding parameters to the end of your URLS using ?

if its a GET request

`"http://localhost/position/route_finder/?arr_ica="+arr_icao+"&dep_icao="+dep_icao`,

or if its a POST request

```
"http://localhost/position/route_finder/"+arr_icao+"/"+dep_icao
```

Answer (score 0):

If `route_finder` is a function with the 2 arguments  then u should use

```
"http://localhost/position/route_finder/" + arr_icao + "/" + dep_icao,
```

if You are going to get the data using `GET` method then use

```
"http://localhost/position/route_finder?arr_icao="+arr_icao+"&dep_icao="+dep_icao,
```

And as you have defined the method post 
you should go for

```
"http://localhost/position/route_finder/" + arr_icao + "/" + dep_icao,
```